# Add a property to nested array objects by locating the parent array object

Tags: json, jolt

I was wondering if I can use jolt to add property on a a nested array object by looking at the parent array object

For example, here is the input.json and I want to add a element called as ownerName in the pet object by looking at the parent owners array object.

**Input.json**

```json
{
  "owners": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "ownerId": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Jack",
          "childId": 11,
          "pets": [
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 2
            },
            {
              "type": "cat",
              "ownerId": 2
            },
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jill",
          "childId": 12,
          "pets": [
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1
            },
            {
              "type": "cat",
              "ownerId": 2
            },
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane",
      "ownerId": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "jack",
          "childId": 21,
          "pets": [
            {
              "type": "rabbit",
              "ownerId": 1
            },
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1
            },
            {
              "type": "cat",
              "ownerId": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**expected output**

```json
{
  "owners": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "ownerId": 1,
      "childs": [
        {
          "name": "Jack",
          "childId": 11,
          "pets": [
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 2,
              "ownerName": "Jane"
            },
            {
              "type": "cat",
              "ownerId": 2,
              "ownerName": "Jane"
            },
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1,
              "ownerName": "John"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jill",
          "childId": 12,
          "pets": [
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1,
              "ownerName": "John"
            },
            {
              "type": "cat",
              "ownerId": 2,
              "ownerName": "Jane"
            },
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1,
              "ownerName": "John"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane",
      "ownerId": 2,
      "childs": [
        {
          "name": "jack",
          "childId": 21,
          "pets": [
            {
              "type": "rabbit",
              "ownerId": 1,
              "ownerName": "John"
            },
            {
              "type": "dog",
              "ownerId": 1,
              "ownerName": "John"
            },
            {
              "type": "cat",
              "ownerId": 2,
              "ownerName": "Jane"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I write Jolt spec for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this spec:

We need a lookup like the following code to know what is our 1 and 2 owner names, which we want to use the name of them. So we want to create a lookup in the first `shift` operation of out spec and we can use it in the second `shift` operation:

```json
{
  "ownerIds": {
    "1": "John",
    "2": "Jane"
  }
}
```

**Jolt Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // owners
        "*": { // 0, 1
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "@(0,name)": "ownerIds.@(0,ownerId)",
          "children": {
            "*": { // 0, 1
              "*": "&4[&3].childs[&1].&",
              "pets": {
                "*": { // 0, 1
                  "*": "&6[&5].childs[&3].&2[&1].&",
                  "ownerId": {
                    "@": "&7[&6].childs[&4].&3[&2].&1",
                    "@0": "&7[&6].childs[&4].&3[&2].lookup.@0"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "owners": {
        "*": { // 0, 1
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "childs": {
            "*": { // 0, 1
              "*": "&4[&3].&2[&1].&",
              "pets": {
                "*": { // 0, 1
                  "*": "&6[&5].&4[&3].&2[&1].&",
                  "lookup": {
                    "*": {
                      "@(8,ownerIds.&)": "&8[&7].&6[&5].&4[&3].ownerName"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Can I do this entire in one single shift operation or can i use any functions of modify-overwrite-beta

Comment: @Rock I don't think so. I think it can't handle in just one operation.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be starting by matching `name` with `ownerId` to be located at the outermost level to be used as a dictionary at the next transformation  by matching them with the `ownerId` attributes again while keeping exact content as a whole through use of `@1` expression such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "owners": {
        "@1": "", // replicate the top level, eg. the current JSON value
        "*": { // reform a dictionary
          "@name": "@ownerId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "owners": {
        "*": { // represents the indexes of the top level array
          "*": "&2[&1].&", // replicate attributes/arrays/objects other than "children" 
          "children": {
            "*": { // represents the indexes of the top level array
              "pets": {
                "*": { // represents the indexes of the top level array
                  "type": "&6[&5].&4[&3].&2[&1].&",
                  "ownerId": {
                    "*": {
                      "@8,&": "&8[&7].&6[&5].&4[&3].ownerName"
                      // loop through the attributes of the dictionary 
                      // those are located 8 levels up
                    },
                    "@": "&7[&6].&5[&4].&3[&2].&" 
                      // replicate the "ownerId" attribute
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```